# Trouble splitting up data evenly?

Tags: r, split, dataframe, rep

I am trying to split up data evenly in R. For example, I am using the dataset cars that is built into R Studio with 50 lines. If I want to split the data into two sections, I would do something along the lines of this:
`cars$split <- rep(1:2, each=25)` where I would create a column called `split` and assign the first 25 values to a 1, and the next 25 values to a 2. However, if I wanted to split my data into, lets say, 8 sections (based on user discretion), I would not be able to divide 50 / 8 evenly as it equals to 6.25. In this case, I would simply assign the last two rows (since 50 / 8 = 6.25, and 6 * 8 = 48 so we would have 2 rows left over) to the number 8 in this case using the function above. However, I am unable to do this since the `rep` function needs to divide properly so I tried to write out some logic as so, but I get an issue saying:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "split", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : replacement has 48 rows, data has 50
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? My attempt is shown below:

```
numDataPerSection <- floor(nrow(cars) / userInputNum)
if(nrow(cars) %% userInputNum != 0){
  #If not divisible, assign last few data points to the last number
  cars$split <- rep(1:ncls, each=numDataPerSection, len = nrow(cars) - (nrow(cars) %% userInputNum))
  for(i in nrow(cars) %% userInputNum){
    cars$split[nrow(cars) - i] <- userInputNum 
  }
}
#Everything divides correctly
else{
  cars$split <- rep(1:ncls, each=numDataPerSection)
}
```

Comment: `findInterval(1:50, seq(0, 50, by=7))`

Comment: @Khashaa this works well but what about the remaining values? In your example, the last row, row 50, would be equal to 8. How would I get it so that it equals 7?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a function such as this one to create your indices?

```
create.indices <- function(nrows, sections) {
  indices <- rep(1:sections,each=floor(nrows/sections))
  indices <- append(indices, rep(tail(indices, 1), nrows%%sections))
  return(indices)
}

create.indices(50,8)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
split1 <- function(n,s){ c( rep(1:s, each=n%/%s), rep(s, n%%s) ) } 
cars$split <- split1(nrow(cars,userInputNum))
```

but this is not very balanced as in your example category 8 is two larger than any other, and would be worse with 55 rows and 8 sections:

```
> split1(50,8)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7
[39] 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
> table(split1(50,8))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 8
> table(split1(55,8))
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 6  6  6  6  6  6  6 13
```

You could do better with something like

```
split2 <- function(n,s){ ((1:n)*s+n-s) %/% n }
```

which produces

```
> split2(50,8)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6
[39] 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8
> table(split2(50,8))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
7 6 6 6 7 6 6 6 
> table(split2(55,8))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `length.out` argument of `rep()` to create your `split` column: `rep(1:8, length.out = 50, each = round(50/8))`. Using the `round()` function works reasonably well to achieve a uniform distribution of group sizes:

```
> table(rep(1:8, length.out = 50, each = round(50/8)))

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
8 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```